# Diferencias ente Spring boot y Spring MVC

Tags: web, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Veo que al ejecutar una aplicación de Spring boot levanta un servidor en el 8080, quisiera saber cual es la diferencia entre estas dos vertientes, con un ejemplo claro tal vez.

Answer (score 6):

Estás comparando dos cosas distintas, intento aclararte los conceptos:

**Spring MVC** *no existe* como framework hoy día, es parte de Spring Framework, del que han salido distintas extensiones como Spring HATEOAS, Spring REST Data...

**Spring Boot** es algo totalmente diferente: es un empaquetado para crear aplicaciones J2EE de manera rápida y con todo incluído. Puedes crear un archivo JAR que incluye hasta las librerías de Tomcat, con que no necesitas tener un servidor instalado, basta con escribir en la línea de comandos java -jar .jar y ya tienes una aplicación web con los puertos listos para recibir llamadas. De hecho, la manera más sencilla de crear un proyecto con spring boot es descargarte un  "esqueleto" de la aplicación generado a medida desde la web https://start.spring.io/

Por tanto, es habitual usar Spring boot para crear tu aplicación y que ésta haga uso de los componentes conocidos como Spring MVC para servir tus datos.

Comment: Gracias amigo! Me abrió el panorama tu aclaración